# How to receive props in another components other than children components pages that are used in layout.js in NextJs 13

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to generate static params for translating languages in next js throught all components
and I am able to receive the language params as prop in all children pages but not in the components that are defined in the layout. in my case i.e SideComponent

> Refer to this doc for more info https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

> app/[lng]/Layout.js

```
import { dir } from 'i18next'
import { languages } from '../i18n/settings'
import SideComponent from "../../comp/component"

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return languages.map((lng) => ({ lng }))
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: {
    lng
  }
}) {
  return (
    <html lang={lng} dir={dir(lng)}>
      <head />
      <body style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <SideComponent />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

comp/component.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default async function SideComponent ({ params: { lng } }) {
    const { t } = await useTranslation(lng, 'second-page')
  return (
    <div>
      Hello sidebar
      {t('back-to-home')}
    </div>
  )
}
```

> app/[lng]/second-page/page.jsx

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Page({ params: { lng } }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hi from second page!</h1>
      <Link href={`/${lng}`}>
        back
      </Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have a sidebar component in my real project which is also defined in such a way in layout.js so that it retains in all the pages but I am not able to put translations in that component.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can pass the language as a prop from the layout

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: {
    lng
  }
}) {
  return (
    <html lang={lng} dir={dir(lng)}>
      <head />
      <body style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <SideComponent lng={lng} />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

---

```js
export default async function SideComponent ({ lng }) {
    const { t } = await useTranslation(lng, 'second-page')
  return (
    <div>
      Hello sidebar
      {t('back-to-home')}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Type '{ lng: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'lng' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
(property) lng: any

Comment: Modify the `SideComponent` to receive it as a prop